# Beginner grappling with octave and mex issues

Tags: c++, namespaces, octave, mex

I'm an experienced C/C++ developer, but I'm extremely green when it comes to dealing with mex in octave. I'm sure I'm missing something basic here, but I can't find what it is.

These are my files:

```
myhello.cpp   
test.cpp   
test.h
```

Here are the contents of the files

(myhello.cpp):

```
#include "test.h"
#include "mex.h"

using namespace test;

void
mexFunction (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
             int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
  mexPrintf ("Hello, World!\n");
  testMethod();

  mexPrintf ("I have %d inputs and %d outputs\n", nrhs, nlhs);
}
```

(test.h)

```
namespace test
{
        void testMethod();
}
```

(test.cpp)

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace test;

void testMethod()
{
        cout << "this works." << endl;
}
```

So then I launch Octave 4.0.0 through ./run-octave --no-gui, and type the following at the prompt:

> mex -v myhello.cpp test.cpp

The response I get is:

> g++ -c  -fPIC
>   -I/usr/local/include/octave-4.0.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/include/octave-4.0.0/octave -I/usr/local/include -pthread -fopenmp -g -O2   -I.  myhello.cpp -o myhello.o g++ -c  -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/octave-4.0.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/include/octave-4.0.0/octave -I/usr/local/include -pthread -fopenmp -g -O2   -I.  test.cpp -o test.o g++ -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic  -o myhello.mex  myhello.o test.o   -L/usr/local/lib/octave/4.0.0 -L/usr/local/lib -loctinterp -loctave

And I'm once again presented with the prompt.

I type

> myhello(1,2,3)

And get this:

> error: /home/brush/Documents/mex_tests/myhello.mex: failed to load:
>   /home/brush/Documents/mex_tests/myhello.mex: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN4test10testMethodEv

So obviously something isn't linking properly, but I cannot figure out how to get everything to do so. Sorry, but I've searched for a while and haven't found anything that fixed this simple issue.

Thanks in advance, 
Ben

P.S. My system is Ubuntu 15.04, 64-bit.

Comment: Try with `-v` to see if there are any more clues.  Also, this is a long shot, but try putting `#include "mex.h" `  first.  It's like it thinks `testMethod` is extern... or dynamically loaded.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't `void testMethod()` be _defined_ in test.CPP in `namespace test`?

Comment: @chappjc I was getting a number of foreign, weird errors in the code (I usually work in Microsoft Visual Studio), but to get mex to compile I had to include the namespace at the start of the test.cpp file and then define the function after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't even compile (link, actually) in VS2013 unless I define `void testMethod()` in `namespace test`.  This works:

```
//test.cpp
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace test
{
    void testMethod()
    {
            cout << "this works." << endl;
    }
}
```

Without `namespace test{ ... }`, there are unresolved symbols:

> myhello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl test::testMethod(void)"

When it works, I get:

```
>> myhello
Hello, World!
I have 0 inputs and 0 outputs
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I did originally, but either there was a weird syntax error or mex just didn't take it; it kept complaining about another issue...I'm away at the moment but will respond with the details in a bit. 

FWIW, I have been fighting with this EXACT same linker-like error with some other code I recently downloaded. That's why I created this simple program.

Comment: @Ben OK, but without defining it in the test namespace, there will be unresolved symbols.  I get them at build time, and you get them at runtime.  Not sure why though.  The output of the program is correct though.

Comment: that was my understanding too. I will try again. Perhaps I just did something stupid? 

I am doing this in VIM, and so it's possible I've become accustomed to intellisense and the red squiggly lines of VS :)

I had assumed that since it compiled and linked, it was working...perhaps mex works differently.

Comment: @Ben I wouldn't blame you -- I can hardly program at all without command completion courtesy of intellisense.  BTW, `stdout` is usually not the MATLAB command prompt, so `cout` may not be visible.

Comment: Well...I have egg on my face, I guess. I did JUST what I thought I had done previously with the code (as you showed above), and it worked this time. 

Presumably the code I was trying to get working earlier has the same quirk in it (I modeled this code after it in an attempt to isolate what wasn't compiling). 

I guess thanks are in order.